# Is there an alternative to MarkItUp?

Tags: javascript, editor, markdown, markitup

I'd like to allow my user to write text using Markdown (Github flavored to be more specific) and I'd like to suggest an editor that provides icons such as Bold, Italic etc that will update the content of the textarea accordingly.

**I don't want the editor to be packaged with a Markdown compiler** (like the one used here, at Stack Overflow) because the compilation will be made server side.

The only possible editor I found was [Mark It Up](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/) but I'd like to know if there is some other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at multiple editors, but this one seems to do it with best style: https://github.com/lepture/editor